# Azure storage jars are not loading in JAVA RMI Server Code not reachable

Tags: java, azure, jar, loading, rmi

We have included the `Azurestorage.jar`, `jackson.jar`, `slf4j.jar` to our projects which contains RMI Server class. But when we execute from .exe and communicate to RMI server, the azure storage class connectivity is not established but the same is working for batch file.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Could you describe clearly the details of your project? If you got some information about errors or exceptions, please post here too.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, It seems that you might not set the option `-cp` or `-classpath` for importing jar files to at the startup of `java.exe` which the `.exe` as you said. Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html to know the option `classpath` for java runtime.